# Does C# allow to do the same as Java 8 now can for Interface Class

Tags: java, c#, interface

From  [this blog](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/java-8-tutorial-default-and-static-methods-guide/):

> I’ve been programming in Java for over 16 years and teaching it for nearly half that time. So it’s going to take a little practice to stop repeating this sentence: “Interfaces may only contain methods that are public and abstract.”  As of Java 8, that statement is no longer true.  It is now possible to add both instance and static methods to Java interfaces.

Does new C# version allow this also or will in some intended future?

I always felt Interface was good in theory but in practice caused many kind of maintenance nightmare on your interface consumers as described in the article.

Update : I'm also interested by the critics, all the more if you have read the author's article especially about abstract class alternative as not solving real world problem.

Comment: For me, these "improvements" sound awful. Default method in a interface? Are you kidding? If you have some basic common logics, define an abstract class with `virtual` method. Interface is a great tool which helps to separate a definition and implementation. "Default" methods absolutely do not follow this logic.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I wouldn't write it off just yet to be honest until I see how it's used in action.I believe the main reason they added it was support Lambda extensions in their collections which C# already addresses perfectly well with extension methods and I don't think we need another way of doing what is already possible in C# but we have to see if people come up with ingenious things to make it make sense outside of adding extensions to existing things.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I hope the Java designers have some basic common logics ;) this is already there not some feature request, can you counter the author's argument precisely.

Answer (score 1):

It is to the implementing class in C# to determine the scope of the method or property implemented. C# knows [implicit and explicit interface implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx), which helps to set the scope of the method. (You can create a secondary method or property that has the wanted scope (`internal`, `private`, `protected`).

Static interface methods are not possible in C# and I wonder why you would want that. Static methods are bound to the type and not to the instance, so you can't call `this.StaticMethod` for example. That makes defining them on interfaces useless.

And default methods are just... horrible. Make an `abstract` class. Period.

Comment: Static methods in interfaces allow you to put utility methods in the appropriate place, e.g. `Comparator.comparingBy`. I'm not 100% convinced about default methods in interfaces either, but I personally think it's a better solution than C# extension methods to the problem of how to evolve interfaces without breaking existing code.

Comment: I don't see extension methods as a fix for evolving interfaces problems. There are other ways to solve those. Not able to rely on the compiler for telling me what to implement is worse in my opinion.

Comment: @PaulBoddington `default` methods are useful if you have one method that relies on another. For example, you may have an interface `Comparable<T>` which provides two methods: `int compareTo(Comparable<T>)` and `Comparator<T> comparator()`. `comparator` would have a `default`implementation which returns a `Comparator<T>` which calls `compareTo()` on the original object.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the article's author of course mentioned abstract class but it has drawbacks also : what do you think if you have read him, if not I suggest you do, it would interest me.